# How do I make a second row using Bootstrap Twitter's container and rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, rows

I have looked over [Bootstrap's documentation on the matter](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) and tried different variations of their stuff, like using container instead of container-fluid, but I have not yet had success.  I am simply trying to make two rows of text.  The following displays on a single row, and I cannot figure out why.  It appears like it should display two different rows, but this is not the case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rows</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2"/>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple1</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple3</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2"/>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple4</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple5</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple6</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My wanted output is something along these lines:

```
        Apple1    Apple2    Apple3

        Apple4    Apple5    Apple6
```

Does anyone know why this is all staying in a single row?

Comment: Why are you using `col-md-offset-2`? And each row should total 12.

Comment: @j08691 because I want to center my row.  Is my approach wrong?

Comment: No, your approach is fine. They don't *have* to total 12, as long as you specify when your row should end with a closing `</div>` Your markup is incorrect as DrCord's answer shows.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you want to center your divs. Should each one take up two columns, leaving three empty columns on each side?

Comment: @j08691 Oops!  I neglected my empty <div class="col-md-1"> tags between cells

Comment: Can you update the code in your question then?

Comment: Updated it. Also, may I ask reason for close vote so that I may  better prepare my questions in the future?

Comment: I see you updated the code, but the example you posted seems to work and not be on one line: http://www.bootply.com/muBUlFJg8K

Comment: oops. i updated the fixed code. haha. let me break it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><p>Apple1</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple3</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><p>Apple4</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple5</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><p>Apple6</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/UJMRxhV0nB)**

The offset should be used together with a grid class, like `class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"`. Having an empty div with just an offset, like `<div class="col-md-offset-2"></div>` doesn't make much sense as it renders with no effect on the layout.

Comment: Oh excellent. this actually fixes my alignment problem as well

Comment: Do you know why my question was downvoted and voted to close?  I would like to not make the same mistake again, but I am unclear what that mistake is.

Comment: @Evorlor - Those are the mysteries of SO. You never know the reasons for votes sometimes. I would guess the someone downvoted because the question was either unclear, or because the code kept changing. I just added an upvote to cancel out the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

because you cannot end a div with `/` in the start tag, you have to end it with `</div>`

these are not ended `<div class="col-md-offset-2"/>` at the point you are expecting them to, but instead where the browser decides that they have to be to keep the DOM from breaking...

see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DrCord/8sq9cb7s/

Comment: Where were you 3 hours ago!?  Thanks!!

Comment: I was working on a personal project :D happy to help!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't appear to resemble the desired outcome at all.

Comment: I tried creating a fiddle myself before I posted question...it is displaying different than expected. I am assuming because of md col size. His answer did fix my problem tho

Comment: The fiddle and answer fix the stated problem of "Does anyone know why this is all staying in a single row?"

Comment: Your fiddle is fine, you just have to resize it to see the correct rendering. The default `result` pane is `sm` (in bootstrap size) not `md`.